# what exactly does 'National Focus' do in Victoria 2?

Tags: victoria-2

When I want to have more clerks in a province, I set the NF on it to get clerks and they magically increase. Does the National Focus add people on top of what the province would get on its own? Or does it increase the % rate?

Related question: I want more clergy so I set NF for that in the province. Does the effect increase if I lower taxes for the poor so more people promote to clergy? Or should I just stick the NF and forget about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect is different depending on the type of focus being applied. In the case of encouraging POP types like Clerks, it increases the likelihood of other POPs promoting to that type by 10%. See the wiki page for [National Focus](http://www.victoria2wiki.com/National_focus) for more information.

As for the effects of taxation, I don't believe these is a direct link between tax levels and promotion. However there is a link between the needs your POPs can fulfil and their chance to promote or demote, and lowering taxes for an income band would mean those POPs have more money for them to spend on those needs.

**Important note:** only Life needs as looked at when calculating a POP's chance to promote (fulfilling them makes promotion *more* likely), while all three needs are examined when calculating a POP's chance to demote (fulfilling various needs for each class band makes demotion *less* likely). Therefore to promote more clerks you would need to decrease taxes for the middle class, not the lower class. See the wiki page on [Promotion](http://www.victoria2wiki.com/Promotion) for more information.

Comment: well question was in March so I now know a whole lot more, but for future generations this answer is very valid.  But on the 'important note'... If I reduce the tax on middle class, won't that make existing clerks more likely to promote to high class (aristocrats/capitalists)?

Comment: Yes, it will have that effect - decreasing tax for the middle class will give them the money to fulfil more of their needs, making them more likely to promote to rich POPs (if Life needs are fulfilled) and less likely to demote to poor POPs (if other needs are also filled). However, you also need to think about the chance for the rich POPs to *stay* rich - bearing in mind that richer POPs also have greater needs to fulfil to avoid being demoted again. Honestly, it makes my head hurt a bit thinking about it. :)